# SCDF task execution created a new entry task name org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@36d4b5c

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

**The Problem**
Created a task on SCDF with a specified name TASK1

- the jar is packaged with main class that is an enhanced version of CommandLineJobLuncher (not annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`), which launches a Spring Batch job.
- There are two Spring configuration, one defines all application required bean, and the other one defines batch job, with `@EnableTask` and `@EnableBatchProcessing`
- Launch the task
- task is launched, but an additional task execution entry is created and named as `org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@36d4b5c`
- The batch job is executed successfully, but is not linked to task definition

research shows that this is how Spring Cloud Task name task, but I don't quite understand why the task name is NOT passed from SCDF as expected. 
Besides, task name becomes as "application" when launch as `@SpringBootApplication`.

Could any one advise how to ensure single task execution entry per task launch?

Comment: Created a @SpringBootApplication and then the task can be launched with single task execution and linked to the batch job properly.
The question is that if the same can be achieved by using CommandLineJobRunner

Comment: Hi, It would be helpful if you share a sample of your app configuration via Git to understand it better?

Comment: I have reproduced the problem with sample code on https://github.com/wangjinhai/spring-batch-test

Comment: Two rows are inserted in TASK_EXECUTION after launching the job on SCDF.

Comment: It's believe that spring.cloud.task.name is NOT passed from SCDF when the JAR is NOT run as spring application.
When enforcing spring.cloud.task.name as the value as task name defined on SCDF, there are still two task execution entries created. The first one doesn't have start date/end date/exit code updated, but the second one does.